# How to add files with JSX to Html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

Tell me please, how to connect external files with JSX to Html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<input value={null} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

But if I copy code inside the "script" tag, everything works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<input value={null} />, document.getElementById('root'))
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors at console?

Comment: for example about cross origin

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>Add React in OneMinute</title></head><body><div id="input_container"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="input.js"></script></body></html>
```

input.js

```
"use strict";const e = React.createElement;class InputContainer extends React.Component {constructor(props) {super(props);}render() {
return e("input");}}const domContainer =document.querySelector("#input_container");ReactDOM.render(e(InputContainer), domContainer);
```

Comment: Yeah, it's possible like that, but it's without JSX. Wondering, how to make the same with JSX.

Comment: you can read documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: Already tried to add a script tag with babel.
And the result is finally the same:

Works without JSX code inside tag script in HTML.
Works with JSX code inside tag script in HTML.
Works from external file without JSX.
Doesn't work from an external file with JSX.